# How to add a bullet in textarea at the beginning of each sentences

Tags: javascript, jquery, textarea

How can I add a new bullet at the beginning of each sentences? for example at the moment the bullets get added next to each other, see below.

**Current behaviour:**

• • hello world
hello world

**While I'd like to have this:**

• hello world
• hello world

```js
$('.add-bullet').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().next('textarea').val(function(idx, value){
        return '\u2022 ' + value;
    });
    return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div><a href="#" class="add-bullet">Add bullet</a></div>
    <textarea type="text"  name="tata" placeholder="Write something.." ></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a regex to check whether there is a bullet at the start of string or after a newline, and if not, add one there:

```js
$('.add-bullet').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().next('textarea').val(function(idx, value){
        return value.replace(/(^|\n)([^\u2022])/u, '$1\u2022 $2');
    });
    return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div><a href="#" class="add-bullet">Add bullet</a></div>
    <textarea type="text"  name="tata" placeholder="Write something.." ></textarea>
```